# Fuzzy set addition and squaring

Tags: python, addition, fuzzy

I'm working with fuzzy sets. I was wondering if there are any libraries available for Python? Namely, I'm having trouble adding 2 fuzzy sets and also squaring them. I am storing the fuzzy set in a Python dictionary, the key being the member element and the value is the membership value.

My sets are:

```
set_A = {'3':0.1, '4': 0.8, '5': 0.5}
set_B = {'6':0.6, '7': 0.2, '8': 0.7}
```

I want to find out `set_A + set_B`

and also `set_A^2 + set_B^2`

Comment: So what would the result be in your example?

Comment: Output for the sum is ​{'0':​ ​0.7,​ ​'1':​ ​0.6,​ ​'2':​ ​0.5} @L3viathan

Comment: For squaring, I used a different fuzzy set, C = {'-1':1, '0':0.4, '1':0.2, '2':0.5}
D = {'-1':0.5, '0':0.8, '1':1, '4':0.4}
I want to find C^2 + D^2?
Required output is ​{'2':​ ​1,​ ​'1':​ ​0.8,​ ​'17':​ ​0.4,​ ​'0':​ ​0.4,​ ​'16':​ ​0.4,​ ​'5':​ ​0.5,​ ​'4':​ ​0.5,
'20':​ ​0.4}
Thanks in advance. @L3viathan

Comment: What meaning do the "member elements" have, then? Why don't you store it in a list if you throw away the keys afterwards?

Comment: `dict`s are not ordered, so are you sorting on key to add? Or how else are you relating `'3'` to `'6'`?

Comment: use dict.items()! @AChampion

Comment: @MaheshK order is not guaranteed with `dict`s so you could get completely different results depending on what is in the `dict`.

Comment: ...unless you are using Python 3.6, in which case order is retained (despite still not being guaranteed)

Comment: Your example output does not show that and http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/applications/fuzzylogic/Manual/9.html shows element wise addition of the sets. Python has unordered sets and dicts - bruh!

Comment: I suggest you write your own code, SO isn't a code writing service, I'm more than happy to help when you show what you have attempted, as that will perhaps show how you get to your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for certain if there's not already a library for this, but here's quick and simple class that I think does what you expect:

```
class Fuzzy_Set:

    def __init__(self, set):
        self.set = set

    def __add__(self, other):
        retset = {}
        for item in set(self.set.keys()).union(set(other.set.keys())):
            retset[item] = self.set.get(item, 0) + other.set.get(item, 0)

        return retset

    def __pow__(self, power, modulo=None):
        if modulo:
            return {k:v**power%modulo for k, v in self.set.items()}
        else:
            return {k:v**power for k, v in self.set.items()}

    def __mod__(self, other):
        return pow(Fuzzy_Set(self.set), 1, other)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    s1 = Fuzzy_Set({'3':0.1, '4': 0.8, '5': 0.5})
    s2 = Fuzzy_Set({'5': .5, '6':0.6, '7': 0.2, '8': 0.7})
    print(s1 + s2)
    print(s1**2)
    print(Fuzzy_Set({'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3})%2)
```

This implements adding and exponentiation and modulo. The output of `main` is:

```
{'3': 0.1, '6': 0.6, '5': 1.0, '7': 0.2, '8': 0.7, '4': 0.8}
{'3': 0.010000000000000002, '4': 0.6400000000000001, '5': 0.25}
{'1': 1, '2': 0, '3': 1}
```

Comment: How exactly is modulo defined in this context? Modulo of each individual element or something different?

Comment: each individual element..@bendl

Comment: This doesn't produce the suggested output for addition: `​{'0':​ ​0.7,​ ​'1':​ ​0.6,​ ​'2':​ ​0.5}`

Comment: I missed that comment... @MaheshK if you have extra information about the question, please edit it into the question rather than commenting. I now have no idea what you mean by a fuzzy set. That output makes no sense